# How to uninstall MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have tried for 6 hours to uninstall my old MySQL Server and install a new one.

Now I have 6 service from old instalations, which I don't know how to delete, I have NO SINGLE MySQL File on my HDD, but there is a server, because when I try to install it newly, it tells me "current PW" and that it can't start the Service and I don't know why.

I don't know what I should describe, I have deleted every single file on my HDD after a restart, but the server seems still active. I have no idea on which port or how to find out where the server is running.

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume you're running a Windows server here, given your usage of the word "service" and the reference to the password wizard.

To find out what a service is running, go to your Services control panel (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services) and locate the MySQL Service. Right-click it and go to properties.

There will be a "Path to Executable" (just above the "Startup Type"). This is where Windows is finding its MySQL server. The field is even highlitable so you can just copy and paste it straight into Explorer to locate the file.

**However** the correct method of un-installing a MySQL server is to go to Programs, locate MySQL, right-click and go "Un-Install"

**If you are running *nix** and you installed MySQL with `apt-get` the correct method to remove it is `apt-get remove <package>` (where  was the name of the MySQL package you used to install). If you want to make sure you even get rid of the config files and all the rest of the files, then add the `--purge` option to the command.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're installing on Windows, what version?  For XP/2003, first stop any listed MySQL services under the [control panel > administrative tools > services] MMC console.

Then [run > cmd] to get a command prompt (must be logged in as an admin), and type the follwing to delete the MySql services:

SC DELETE [servicename]

That should remove the services, and you can delete any remaining MySQL directories and files manually before reinstalling.